# Почему NullPointerException?

Tags: java, файлы, потоки-данных

NoSuchFileException

```
String path="C:\\Новая папка\\Документ Microsoft Word.docx";
        List<String> list= Files.readAllLines(Path.of(path));
```

FileNotFoundException

```
String path="C:\\Новая папка\\Документ Microsoft Word.docx";
        FileInputStream is=new FileInputStream(path);
```

Почему не видно файл ?

```
StackTrace при добавлении файла в проекта с помощью переноса:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\*...*\Java обучение\Java Пробные классы\untitled\src\main\resources\Word.docx
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:236)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2923)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3413)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3454)
    at Main.main(Main.java:12)
```

Comment: попробуйте имя файла без пробелов брать

Answer (score 0):

Возможные проблемы:

1)Пробелы в пути файла

2)Кириллица вместо латиницы

3)Неверный формат пути (в разных ОС - разные разделители).

4)Файла действительно не существует - либо нет к нему доступа

и т.д.

Comment: Убрал пробелы, переименовал папку и файл используя латиницу, поменял разделители
Проблема осталась

Comment: Почему может не быть доступа?

Comment: @Алексей, как вариант потому что у вас файл на диске C, попробуйте открыть файл чтобы они был на другом диске, для С по-моему нужен админский доступ

Comment: Другого диска нет

Comment: Если я создаю файл непосредственно в проекте и работаю  с ним то всё ок
Но если я переношу файл с диска в проект, то ошибка всё та же.

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать методом исключения. Назовите этот файл латиницей и без пробелов  и разместите его в С:\ получится или нет? Это отбросит половину возможных проблем

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо  использовать  статический  метод get обьекта  Paths.  `List<String> list= Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName ));`

Comment: [`Paths.get()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/nio/file/Paths.java#L69) вызывает `Path.of()`, разницы между этими методами нет.